# Apply for visit visa less than 3 months from Egypt

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, egyptian-citizens

I want to apply for a visit visa for my husband to come see me in the UK (I'm a student and my visa is valid until the end of February 2020).

I want him to be with me in my PhD viva and graduation. He is self-employed and has a contract of the shop he rented. He does not have a travel history before except when he went to my country to marry me. He is Egyptian.

He wants to travel in August. Is it ok to apply on 20 June or will he get rejected? Because I am a student and my financial support ends by end of September (but I'm working part-time) and I am supporting him (I will cover his expenses).

Please, recommend me  what I should do and according to my situation how long he can stay in the UK (we plan from August to December).

Comment: How long is your husband planning to stay in the UK? Are you saying that your student status in the UK is valid until the end of September 2019, and that he cannot cover his travel costs himself? Based on the limited information you’ve given it seems unlikely an application would be successful. It might help you to read this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e and then, if you still want advice from TSE members, edit your question to clarify exactly what you want to know.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, please, I edited the question, can you help, please?

Comment: A 5-month long visit ending shortly before your own visa expires isn’t a good idea, IMHO. UKVI will very probably conclude that there may be an intention to overstay. What is his citizenship? Has he visited you in the UK before? Does he have a travel history to other countries? What ties to his home country does he have (job, family, savings etc)? If he has none of these things, his chance of success is probably very low, if not zero.

Comment: I want him to be with me in my PhD viva and graduation, he is self-employed and has a contract of the shop he rented. He does not have a travel history before except when he went to my country to marry me. He is Egyptian

Answer (score 1):

Your husband can apply up to 3 months before his intended date of travel.

No-one can predict his chances of success. Your PhD viva and graduation is a reasonable premise for his visit, but IMHO it is unlikely to be sufficient to justify a 5 month visit. Planning to be away from his business for so long and being unable to cover the costs of the trip himself is also a red flag.

If you decide to apply I suggest you shorten the intended length of visit to the say 2-3 weeks immediately around your graduation.